# fontconfig-infinality causes 13.04 boot failure

Tags: boot, software-installation

I upgraded my travel notebook (Asus VivoBook X202E 11.6" Touch Screen, but minimal video,  1366x768 as I recall) from ubuntu 12.10 to ubuntu 13.04. Everything worked perfectly, But then I Thought I would make some minor enhancements. did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fontconfig-infinality
```

no install errors.

rebooted

no mouse cursor

dialog box gives options to run in low resolution

neither keyboard or mouse does anything

There are no other (i.e. Linux, Win8 or Win7 boot partitions on this netbook)

booted with a 12.10 install USB,  tried to remove fontconfig-infinality,  but it seems not to be installed (guess all it showed was packages loaded from the USB)

I need a way to 'get in' and undo the effects of "sudo apt-get install fontconfig-infinality"

Answer (score 1):

Boot into recovery mode like [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), and then when it gives you `root@computername~#`, type `apt-get purge fontconfig-infinality` then `add-apt-repository -r ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa`. This should **completely** remove fontconfig-infinality from your system, along with its PPA.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to solve this, just update the init script for System V for Display Manager in Ubuntu:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f lightdm remove
sudo update-rc.d lightdm defaults
```

Original answer is for [mdm](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=206&t=141808).

Answer (score 0):

I got help from this in Mint17 MATE: just changed "-r " with "-rm" to remove repository. All else was the same as the initial problem was the same. 
I looked for some time before i found this and was able to fix the boot problem
and the mdm failure. 
I got into the recovery mode and had to get to the 'drop to shell.. and  mount -o remount,rw /. I had been trying to execute the commands from entering them and got the read only error and was stuck till i found this and the ubuntu wiki for recovery.